# How do I remove the first string on every line in vim?

Tags: linux, text-editor, vi

I have a text file that's thousands of lines long.  Every line starts with a string of 8 hex numbers.  I need to remove this string on every line.  How do I do this in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>^V</kbd> for block select, highlight your eight columns, and delete as normal.

Or use `:s`:

```
:%s/\v^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}//
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace first 8 hex chars (0-9 digits, a-f/A-F letters) on any line with empty string:

```
 :%s/^[0-9a-fA-F]\{8\}//gc
```

Answer (score 1):

If the line is

```
12345678 Something else
```

a total of 9 chars is to be removed from the head of each line, in VIM

```
:1,$s/^.........//
```

should do the trick (9 dots),

- `:` to tell vim you want to enter a command
- `1,$` means the command affects from line 1 to the last (or `g` global)
- `s` means substitute
- `^` means beginning of line
- `.....` means 5 (any) chars
- `s/^.....//` means replace 5 chars at start of line with nothing

*edit* to match the number of hex chars from the question..

Answer (score 1):

use `cut` command. This way is much more **straight forward.**

```
echo '12345678 Something else' | cut -c 10-
```

result:

```
Something else
```

Just remind, `cut` index string start from 1 instead of 0.

In `vi`, we could just run `cut` in `vi`:

```
:%!cut -c 10-
```